# Resize event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to listen for window resize event in react.js. I tried using window.addEventListener but that fires the callback multiple times. Is there a way that the callback runs only once or simply a more react oriented way(a hook maybe) to achieve this?

```
    const resizeQuery = () => {
    console.log("check");
    if (desktop) setnumberOfShownImages(4);
    else if (tablet) setnumberOfShownImages(3);
    else if (mobile) setnumberOfShownImages(1);
  };

    window.addEventListener('resize',resizeQuery);
```

full Component code:

```
function ImageSlider(props) {
  const [numberOfShownImages, setnumberOfShownImages] = useState(props.numberOfShownImages);
  const currentIndex = 0;
  const array = [
                <PrimaryCard imageHeight = "200" imageAlt = "Fox" imagePath = {fox} header = "Fox" description = "This is a 1"/>,
                <PrimaryCard imageHeight = "200" imageAlt = "Fox" imagePath = {fox} header = "Fox" description = "This is a 2"/>,
                <PrimaryCard imageHeight = "200" imageAlt = "Fox" imagePath = {fox} header = "Fox" description = "This is a 3"/>,
                <PrimaryCard imageHeight = "200" imageAlt = "Fox" imagePath = {fox} header = "Fox" description = "This is a 4"/>,
                <PrimaryCard imageHeight = "200" imageAlt = "Fox" imagePath = {fox} header = "Fox" description = "This is a 5"/>,
                <PrimaryCard imageHeight = "200" imageAlt = "Fox" imagePath = {fox} header = "Fox" description = "This is a 6"/>,
                <PrimaryCard imageHeight = "200" imageAlt = "Fox" imagePath = {fox} header = "Fox" description = "This is a 7"/>,
  ];
  const classes = useStyles();

  const theme = useTheme();
  const desktop = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("lg"));
  const tablet = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("sm"));
  const mobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("xs"));

  const resizeQuery = () => {
    console.log("Mahad0");
    if (desktop) setnumberOfShownImages(4);
    else if (tablet) setnumberOfShownImages(3);
    else if (mobile) setnumberOfShownImages(1);
  };

    window.addEventListener('resize',resizeQuery);

  return (
    <div className={classes.paper}>
        <IconButton aria-label="delete" color="primary">
            <ArrowBackIosNewIcon fontSize='large' color='secondary'/>
        </IconButton>
        {
            array.slice(currentIndex, numberOfShownImages)
        }
        <IconButton aria-label="delete" color="primary">
            <ArrowForwardIosIcon fontSize='large' color='secondary'/>
        </IconButton>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for the entire component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use windowsize hook

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// Usage
function App() {
  const size = useWindowSize();
  return (
    <div>
      {size.width}px / {size.height}px
    </div>
  );
}
// Hook
function useWindowSize() {
  // Initialize state with undefined width/height so server and client renders match
  // Learn more here: https://joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    // Handler to call on window resize
    function handleResize() {
      // Set window width/height to state
      setWindowSize({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      });
    }
    // Add event listener
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    // Call handler right away so state gets updated with initial window size
    handleResize();
    // Remove event listener on cleanup
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount
  return windowSize;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need to fire a callback when the window resizes. if I am not wrong then this function returns me the current size of the window. How would I integrate my callback into this code?

Comment: will be affected every time the window size is changed. you can use useeffect to add a callback.  `useEffect(()=> { // calback }, [size.window])`